# Best practice for post-processing of multiple concurrent messages

Tags: concurrency, architecture, microservices, jms, amazon-sqs

I have the following situation:

- User requests something;
- The request is split into multiple parts/batches/messages;
- These messages are consumed by multiple consumers, concurrently/horizontally;
- After ALL messages are processed/consumed, I still need to do some processing and return the result.

The last part is where I'm stuck. The best I've got is:

- Create a register somewhere (redis/mongo) with the total of messages generated and the current ammount of finished messages;
- Increment this register at the end of every consumed message (making sure there's no concurrency error, in case 2 consumers try to update it at the exact same time);
- Create a separate FIFO Queue;
- Send a message to this second Queue when every message from the first queue finishes processing, all with the same group-id;
- Consume this second queue, checking the redis/mongo register for each message received, discarding every message until it's the one with an equivalent total of messages generated and processed.

I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution to this scenario, but I can't find it, possibly 'cause I'm using the wrong terms when I search for it.

If it's relevant, I'm using AWS SQS with spring-cloud/spring-boot microservices.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a solution by combining various queues and storage systems, but such a solution would likely be unsightly and challenging to manage and diagnose.

Your problem is much better solved by an orchestrator like [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) or [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/). Here is the [split-join example](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/main/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/hello/HelloParallelActivity.java) taken from Temporal Java SDK Samples:

```
public List<String> getGreetings(List<String> names) {
      List<String> results = new ArrayList();

      List<Promise<String>> promiseList = new ArrayList<>();
      if (names != null) {
        for (String name : names) {
          promiseList.add(Async.function(activities::composeGreeting, "Hello", name));
        }

        // Invoke all activities in parallel. Wait for all to complete
        Promise.allOf(promiseList).get();

        // Loop through promises and get results
        for (Promise<String> promise : promiseList) {
          if (promise.getFailure() == null) {
            results.add(promise.get());
          }
        }
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
```

Note that this code keeps running as nothing happened in the presence of various failures and process crashes. So it is guaranteed to complete.